# How to dynamically create an Azure Service Bus Subscription using Spring Cloud Stream Binder?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-servicebus-topics

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-with-service-bus), a topic subscription can be created upfront using the portal. My requirement is to create the subscription on the fly. Is there way to configure spring cloud binder like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can create subscription on the fly in your Stream Binder classes. But you might consider creating that in application startup (like 'main' method of the application) as bootstrapping logic.

Note: To create the subscription your service bus connection string should have manage permission. So be careful about the security aspect of exposing higher privilege to application.